# Refresh blank screen issue in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

I am using Angular Pages template, whenever I redirect to any page or refresh I usually get a blank screen saying "Unknown service Provider" is that the problem of lazy load or something else which is causing the issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using resolver as mentioned https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve which waits for page to load till you get your data from the source.